# How to talk to other cells from within UITableViewCell in Swift2 UITableViewController?

Tags: uitableview, swift2

Is it possible - and how - to talk to any other visible UITableViewCell from within another cell inside a UITableView?

I have two kinds of cells, lets say blue and red ones. the distribution of the two kinds of cells inside the listview is randomly. the problem I need to solve is: I want to make all visible red cell communicate.
Thnx!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to communicate without passing pointers, defining protocols and delegates is always **NSNotification**.

You can think of NSNotification as a kind of "switchboard" which allows you to pass custom messages across your app, without worrying about "connecting" all dots.

You post notifications with postNotification,
you must set observers and their target methods in the object in which you want to handle the notifications.

You could set different cells to different UITableViewCell derived classes, and post/receive notifications among them.

Remember to:
- remove observers before the object they contain gets deallocated (e.g. in viewWillDisappear for viewControllers, etc).
- don't add your observers twice.

Comment: This is an interestig approach, but for my concerns I need to check just the visible cells. Your solution sounds like many many notification listeners.
I will edit my question to be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe for some cases it would be enough to use the simple

```
let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
```

to solve the problem!